# Migrating code from Jena 2 to 3

Tags: semantic-web, apache-jena

Which class has replaced com.hp.hpl.jena.db.IDBConnection in Jena 3.x.x?

I have tried to use org.apache.jena.db but it seems not to be there.

Comment: Seems to have a very old version - RDB (which is ... jena.db) was removed well before the end of Jena2.

Answer (score 1):

The provided database storage systems are :

- TDB - a custom (non-SQL) triple storage layer.
- SDB - an SQL-backed triple  storage layer.

TDB is preferred, it scales better and is faster.  SDB is for when you really must have an SQL based solution.